# chkrootkit scanner detected possible KLM Trojan

Tags: antivirus, rootkit

Today I scanned my machine with the `chkrootkit` tool by running:

```
sudo chkrootkit
```

And this was some of the output:

> Checking `lkm'...                                           You have
>   2 process hidden for readdir command You have     2 process hidden for
>   ps command chkproc: Warning: Possible LKM Trojan installed chkdirs:
>   nothing detected

Is this anything to worry about? And if so, how can I remedy the situation?

I am running Ubuntu 14.10 and `chkrootkit` version 0.49.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Is this anything to worry about?

No, it is a false positive and a long standing bug in chrootkit. You will see the message any time the lkm check reports hidden processes inaccessible by the readdir command. If you have something like ClamAV, MySQL, Exim or MailScanner running you are bound to see this warning.

Easiest check: run chrootkit a couple of times with as many services stopped (ie. mysql, clamav etc). If the results vary it is a clear indicator it is a false positive.

By the way: rkhunter has a better check for lkm.

---

Some random topics about this message: [stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162859/the-chkproc-warning-possible-lkm-trojan-installed-appears-and-disappears), [cpanel.net](http://forums.cpanel.net/f5/lkm-trojan-hidden-process-chkrootkit-false-alarm-24733.html), [Linuxquestions.org](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-security-4/chkrootkit-warning-of-lkm-trojan-242318/) and all state this is bogus and a bug.

---

Something extra: the command `./chkproc -v` will show the process ids (PID) for the message you get and you can use that to find the program that is connected to this process with `cd /proc/{PID}/ && cat cmdline`

In case this is convincing enough you can stop reading. If you want to know about your machine and how things work keep reading.

---

> So what do you need to know about your system to be able to tackle this problem?

Firstly: The best rootkit detector is you. Knowing what services are active on your machine, knowing what scripts are running on your machine is what keeps your system clean and safe. And yes it will take a bit of time to fully understand a Linux system.

Secondly: [There is a bit of malware targeting Linux](http://www.securityweek.com/newly-discovered-turla-malware-targets-linux-systems) but it is rare. For the simple reason that although Linux is very portable it is not that portable. The differences between distributions (how ever so small), libraries, different kernels and compilers make executing random code on random machines extremely difficult. And the people that are into malware are in it for financial gain. So they focus on Windows for the very simple reasons that it is closed source, has a lot of holes that depend on Microsoft to take action to fix them. (simplified :) )

---

Now for the warning you see about a possible LKM Trojan installed. LKM stands for Linux Kernel Module and is one of the core modules in Linux. Kernel modules are loaded into matching kernels and if the two do not belong together the modules will not load.  This is one of the basic security features of a Linux system that you can use for tracking down malicious code (1).

Some basic things about kernels (2):

- `uname -r` shows your kernel.
- the kernels installed can be viewed in `/boot`.

  `rinzwind@schijfwereld:/boot$ ls 
    abi-3.16.0-22-generic         initrd.img-3.16.0-29-generic
    abi-3.16.0-23-generic         initrd.img-3.16.0-30-generic
    abi-3.16.0-24-generic         memtest86+.bin
    abi-3.16.0-25-generic         memtest86+.elf
    abi-3.16.0-28-generic         memtest86+_multiboot.bin
    abi-3.16.0-29-generic         System.map-3.16.0-22-generic
    abi-3.16.0-30-generic         System.map-3.16.0-23-generic
    config-3.16.0-22-generic      System.map-3.16.0-24-generic
    config-3.16.0-23-generic      System.map-3.16.0-25-generic
    config-3.16.0-24-generic      System.map-3.16.0-28-generic
    config-3.16.0-25-generic      System.map-3.16.0-29-generic
    config-3.16.0-28-generic      System.map-3.16.0-30-generic
    config-3.16.0-29-generic      vmlinuz-3.16.0-22-generic
    config-3.16.0-30-generic      vmlinuz-3.16.0-23-generic
    grub                          vmlinuz-3.16.0-24-generic
    initrd.img-3.16.0-22-generic  vmlinuz-3.16.0-25-generic
    initrd.img-3.16.0-23-generic  vmlinuz-3.16.0-28-generic
    initrd.img-3.16.0-24-generic  vmlinuz-3.16.0-29-generic
    initrd.img-3.16.0-25-generic  vmlinuz-3.16.0-30-generic
    initrd.img-3.16.0-28-generic`
- kernel modules are installed in `/lib/modules` in a subdirectory matching your kernel.

---

So based on (1) and (2) the next step is to reboot into another kernel. The offending module was compiled against a specific kernel and will not be able to compile itself into the other kernel (simply because the headers do not match).

---

The amount of directories and files that can be affected when you have a rootkit are limited (a rootkit needs to be started from somewhere). There are 2 directories and a group of files that will be targeted ...

1. `/etc/init.d/`

   Do an `ls -ltr /etc/init.d` (it will list them in order they have been last changed) and check for unknown services. Normal services will have sane names. These services can be started by the system or manually.

   `rinzwind@schijfwereld:/etc/init.d$ ls 
   acpid                   hwclock.sh             reboot
   alsa-utils              irqbalance             resolvconf
   anacron                 kerneloops             rsync
   apparmor                killprocs              rsyslog
   apport                  kmod                   saned
   atieventsd              lightdm                sendsigs
   avahi-daemon            lvm2                   single
   bluetooth               mountall-bootclean.sh  skeleton
   bootmisc.sh             mountall.sh            smartmontools
   brltty                  mountdevsubfs.sh       speech-dispatcher
   cgmanager               mountkernfs.sh         sslh
   cgproxy                 mountnfs-bootclean.sh  sudo
   checkfs.sh              mountnfs.sh            thermald
   checkroot-bootclean.sh  networking             udev
   checkroot.sh            network-manager        udev-finish
   console-setup           ondemand               ufw
   cron                    php5-fpm               umountfs
   cups                    pppd-dns               umountnfs.sh
   cups-browsed            procps                 umountroot
   dbus                    pulseaudio             unattended-upgrades
   dns-clean               rc                     urandom
   grub-common             rc.local               uuidd
   halt                    rcS                    x11-common
   hostname.sh             README`
2. `/etc/rc*/`

   The startup and kill scripts are located in `/etc/rc[0-5,S].d`. In general the files here have numbers and a sane description (these files are executed in alphabetical order when started and in reversed order during a kill. Watch out for scripts consisting of random numbers and letters. Here is a list (these are valid scripts).

   `rinzwind@schijfwereld:/etc$ ls rc*/
   rc0.d/:
   K01alsa-utils    K01lightdm            K01unattended-upgrades  K05umountnfs.sh
   K01atieventsd    K01php5-fpm           K01urandom              K06networking
   K01bluetooth     K01pulseaudio         K01uuidd                K07umountfs
   K01cgmanager     K01resolvconf         K02avahi-daemon         K08umountroot
   K01cgproxy       K01speech-dispatcher  K03sendsigs             K09halt
   K01cups-browsed  K01sslh               K04rsyslog              README
   K01irqbalance    K01thermald           K05hwclock.sh`

   `rc1.d/:
   K01alsa-utils    K01irqbalance     K01speech-dispatcher  README
   K01atieventsd    K01kerneloops     K01sslh               S01dns-clean
   K01bluetooth     K01lightdm        K01thermald           S01killprocs
   K01cgmanager     K01php5-fpm       K01ufw                S01pppd-dns
   K01cgproxy       K01pulseaudio     K01uuidd              S02single
   K01cups          K01saned          K02avahi-daemon
   K01cups-browsed  K01smartmontools  K04rsyslog`

   `rc2.d/:
   README        S01uuidd       S02kerneloops         S04cups
   S01apport     S02acpid       S02rsync              S04cups-browsed
   S01cgmanager  S02anacron     S02smartmontools      S04pulseaudio
   S01dns-clean  S02atieventsd  S02speech-dispatcher  S04saned
   S01php5-fpm   S02cgproxy     S02thermald           S05grub-common
   S01pppd-dns   S02cron        S03avahi-daemon       S05ondemand
   S01rsyslog    S02dbus        S03bluetooth          S05rc.local
   S01sslh       S02irqbalance  S03lightdm`

   `rc3.d/:
   README        S01uuidd       S02kerneloops         S04cups
   S01apport     S02acpid       S02rsync              S04cups-browsed
   S01cgmanager  S02anacron     S02smartmontools      S04pulseaudio
   S01dns-clean  S02atieventsd  S02speech-dispatcher  S04saned
   S01php5-fpm   S02cgproxy     S02thermald           S05grub-common
   S01pppd-dns   S02cron        S03avahi-daemon       S05ondemand
   S01rsyslog    S02dbus        S03bluetooth          S05rc.local
   S01sslh       S02irqbalance  S03lightdm`

   `rc4.d/:
   README        S01uuidd       S02kerneloops         S04cups
   S01apport     S02acpid       S02rsync              S04cups-browsed
   S01cgmanager  S02anacron     S02smartmontools      S04pulseaudio
   S01dns-clean  S02atieventsd  S02speech-dispatcher  S04saned
   S01php5-fpm   S02cgproxy     S02thermald           S05grub-common
   S01pppd-dns   S02cron        S03avahi-daemon       S05ondemand
   S01rsyslog    S02dbus        S03bluetooth          S05rc.local
   S01sslh       S02irqbalance  S03lightdm`

   `rc5.d/:
   README        S01uuidd       S02kerneloops         S04cups
   S01apport     S02acpid       S02rsync              S04cups-browsed
   S01cgmanager  S02anacron     S02smartmontools      S04pulseaudio
   S01dns-clean  S02atieventsd  S02speech-dispatcher  S04saned
   S01php5-fpm   S02cgproxy     S02thermald           S05grub-common
   S01pppd-dns   S02cron        S03avahi-daemon       S05ondemand
   S01rsyslog    S02dbus        S03bluetooth          S05rc.local
   S01sslh       S02irqbalance  S03lightdm`

   `rc6.d/:
   K01alsa-utils    K01lightdm            K01unattended-upgrades  K05umountnfs.sh
   K01atieventsd    K01php5-fpm           K01urandom              K06networking
   K01bluetooth     K01pulseaudio         K01uuidd                K07umountfs
   K01cgmanager     K01resolvconf         K02avahi-daemon         K08umountroot
   K01cgproxy       K01speech-dispatcher  K03sendsigs             K09reboot
   K01cups-browsed  K01sslh               K04rsyslog              README
   K01irqbalance    K01thermald           K05hwclock.sh`

   `rcS.d/:
   README             S03udev              S08checkroot-bootclean.sh
   S01console-setup   S04brltty            S08kmod
   S02alsa-utils      S04mountdevsubfs.sh  S08urandom
   S02apparmor        S04procps            S09mountall.sh
   S02hostname.sh     S04udev-finish       S09networking
   S02mountkernfs.sh  S05hwclock.sh        S10mountall-bootclean.sh
   S02resolvconf      S05lvm2              S10mountnfs.sh
   S02ufw             S06checkroot.sh      S11mountnfs-bootclean.sh
   S02x11-common      S07checkfs.sh        S12bootmisc.sh`
3. a startup script.

   In general Ubuntu uses bash in a terminal and dash when booting. `echo $SHELL` will show you what shell is being used. For bash the hidden files to check for weird scripts or weird lines of code are...

   ```
   /etc/profile 
   /etc/bashrc
   /etc/bash.bashrc

   ~/.profile
   ~/.bash_profile
   ```

   These are the 5 common ones. Any machine can have more though. Besides that you might also include

   ```
   /etc/crontab
   crontab
   ```

   The last one for both your user and by doing `sudo su`. "crontab" you can list with `crontab -l`.  Watch for scripts that are not general Linux or created by you.

If you happen to have a second system life becomes a lot easier: you can simply compare all the files above with the second machine.

Comment: Who has reviewed the source code for all of the chkrootkit C programs, especially the script “chkrootkit”, to ensure that they aren’t infecting our computers with rootkits or key loggers?

In other words, how do we know that chkrootkit isn’t malware, disguised as malware detector?

Comment: 1. We trust the maintainers. 2. Debian and Ubuntu repositories are free of malware. By the way: a keylogger is a valid piece of software; there is one in the repositories. 3. The users check them: as soon as 1 of the many users using linux notices a problem you can expect them to post about it on bugzilla or other internet sites. 4. I would notice. My router logs all traffic and I manually check the logs. 5. At some point paranoia becomes a hindrance ... you have to trust someone at some point. We trust our maintainers and we trust Canonical unless proven otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

I know there is already an accepted answer, but I want to show another way on how to debug this, which might help someone else in the future. This helped me to figure out that this was indeed a false positive.
I also stumbled upon output like this on Ubuntu 20.04 using `chkrootkit` v0.53

```
Checking `lkm'...                                           You have    12 process hidden for readdir command
You have    12 process hidden for ps command
chkproc: Warning: Possible LKM Trojan installed
```

Note, that the amount of `12` was changing every time I ran it. So to debug this further I ran `chkproc -v` (usually in `/usr/lib/chkrootkit/`), which gives output like this:

```
PID 277881(/proc/277881): not in readdir output
PID 277881: not in ps output
You have     1 process hidden for readdir command
You have     1 process hidden for ps command
```

Note, that this also changed every time I ran it (different PID, different amount). So it seemed like some (unidentified) short-lived processes were messing with `chkproc`, which is a known source for false positives, see http://www.chkrootkit.org/faq/.
To make my final judgement I needed to identify these short-lived processes and for this I can only recommand using `atop`, which can track process history over time, so that it can tell you what processes have been active over a period of time.

So to debug all this, here is what you need to do:

1. Run `chkproc -v` in one shell and let `atop` run in another shell.
2. When `chkproc` returns you some PID, wait for `atop` to update its output and pause it then (usually `z` key).
3. Have a look at the lower half of the `atop` output where you will find the process list starting with currently active processes and ending with the ones, that have exited during the past `atop` recording period. Such processes will be marked with `<>` in the most right-hand column.
4. Try to find the PID you just saw in `chkproc -v` from step 1. If it's not in there, then you may have paused `atop` too early, so try again in this case. If you can find the PID, then have a look at its `CMD` and `RUID` column entry. That should give you a good hint, what this process *was* and should hopefully give you an idea if this is a false positive or not.

Finally I can mention, that I found a lot of such short-lived processes (e.g. lots of `sleep`), which turned out to be coming Docker containers running web apps on my system. To verify that I stopped all Docker containers temporarily and all these short-lived processes were gone and `chkproc` as well as `chkrootkit` were happy again by not finding anything.

So to sum up: Short-lived processes in Docker containers can cause false-positives. However make sure to identify them first instead of ignoring them right away.