# do i have a rootkit or infected system

Tags: 14.04

I used `chkrootkit` recently and it turned up the following:

```
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/.path
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyQt4/uic/widget-plugins/.noinit
/usr/lib/jvm/.java-1.7.0-openjdk-i386.jinfo
/usr/lib/jvm/.java-8-oracle.jinfo
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/lib/missioncontrol/plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.registry_3.5.100.v20120521-2346/.api_description
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/lib/missioncontrol/p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine/.settings
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/lib/missioncontrol/p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine/profileRegistry/JMC.profile/.lock
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/lib/missioncontrol/p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine/profileRegistry/JMC.profile/.data
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/lib/visualvm/platform/.lastModified
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/lib/visualvm/profiler/.lastModified
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/lib/visualvm/visualvm/.lastModified
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/lib/missioncontrol/p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine/.settings
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/lib/missioncontrol/p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine/profileRegistry/JMC.profile/.data
```

and also:

```
Searching for Suckit rootkit...                             
Warning: /sbin/init INFECTED
```

Comment: Please provide proof you are using an update reference file. How many times did you scan? One? Please do 3, 4 or 5 times and if those turn blank it is a fake warning. 99.9999% of these warnings are due to -normal- changes and an out of date reference file.

Comment: Also have a look here http://askubuntu.com/questions/587872/chkrootkit-scanner-detected-possible-klm-trojan/587903#587903

Comment: "chkrootkit" does not do full checks for additional files with "Suckit rootkit", so almost certainly a false positive, a tool which is much better than this tool and does not make these sorts of mistakes anymore is called "rkhunter", I would recommend that instead of the tool you are using.

Comment: @Toroidal: Could you please convert that to an answer so that schmucks like me who go around hunting for unanswered questions don't have to look at this one any more.  ;-)  (And I'll upvote if you drop me a note and it's a good one too!)

Comment: thanks rinzwind ill try again, i did only scan once from what i believe to be an updated reference file, i should have pointed out im a noob to ubuntu,if there no change ill ask again.

Answer (score 0):

`chkrootkit` does not do full checks for additional files with "Suckit rootkit", so this is almost certainly a false-positive.

A tool which I would instead recommend using is called [`rkhunter`](http://rkhunter.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/rkhunter/rkhunter/files/README), and this is because it does do additional file checks for Suckit Rootkit, and so does not make the same mistake.

You can install rkhunter with:

```
sudo apt-get install rkhunter
```

Read this for more information on `chkrootkit` detecting Suckit Rootkit's presence on the system, when in fact it is not present on the system: https://askubuntu.com/a/25179/364819

Comment: @TonyBartlett: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** under the "0" at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)

Comment: @Fabby: Ah, but it is no longer a `0`. **;-)**

Comment: Sorry I upvoted!  :P  ;-)  But he'll see it when he gets back on-line (2 April last time seen)