# Backdoor.Linux.Gafgyt.A - How to detect an infection with this backdoor.

Tags: rkhunter, chkrootkit, trojan

Yesterday I found out about the existence of the `Backdoor.Linux.Gafgyt.A` trojan backdoor. 
I did run `chkrootkit` vs 0.49 and `rkhunter` 1.40. But surprisingly in the logs, I could not see these programs had this quite new backdoor in their database.

So what is the best way to find out if my computer has no backdoor?

Answer (score 1):

The Trojan in question has an md5sum of 5924BCC045BB7039F55C6CE29234E29A. A long list of products will detect it. Available [here](http://telussecuritylabs.com/threats/show/TSL20140925-03)

Source: http://telussecuritylabs.com/threats/show/TSL20140925-03

Comment: Thanks. But... these are all either trial and then pay software. Or even only windows.... Maybe there is another way? I've seen a very well explained answer here, [link](http://askubuntu.com/a/587903/114007) , but is there a way to do a quick search. Can you explain me for example how to search and find trojans with the md5sum?

Comment: You'd have to write a script. you could start with this: `find . -type f -name '*' -exec md5sum {} \;` and then grep the output for the known md5sum. Honestly it would be simpler to use the trial software.